# how to quickly create dummy image directly in .NET code

Tags: c#, winforms, image, random

How to quickly create some **random image** with the icon size?
I don't want to use neither `Image.FromFile`, nor `Image.FromStream`

Comment: You will have to be a little biut more clear than that. Please try to explain what you are attempting to achieve, or show us what you have tried.

Comment: I simply want to assign some random Icons / Images to all elements implementing an IHasImage interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int width = 50;
int height = 50;
using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
{

    // do something to the bitmap
    // perhaps use .SetPixel to maybe apply some color

    bitmap.Save("C:\\Temp\\random.bmp");
}
```

Comment: Its useful to declare Graphics object? which has more functions to edit picture. 
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics_members%28v=VS.71%29.aspx